# I want to post form data using codeigniter but I am getting this error . How to do this?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to post input text to my controller but when i run "The page isn't redirecting properly" error has come and index.php is automatically appear in url like this "http://localhost:1337/PhpProject1/search_profile_controller/Index.php". I have removed index.php from my url by htaccess ! my code is here

```
class Search_profile_controller extends CI_Controller{

public function profile_clicked(){       
$data = $this->input->post('input_profile');        
$this->load->view('profile_view',$data);     
echo $data;     
}

}
```

my html

```
<form id="frm" name="frm" action="http://localhost:1337/PhpProject1/search_profile_controller/profile_clicked" method="post" >       

// I input value from jquery and submit it dynamically                
</form>
```

my route.php

```
$route['search_profile_controller/(:any)'] =   'search_profile_controller';
$route['search_profile_controller/(:any)'] =   'search_profile_controller/profile_clicked';
```

Comment: Just a idea you could use codeigniter form helper for you view saves you putting in full url. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: change in your route file. remove both lines and write $route['search_profile_controller'] = 'search_profile_controller/profile_clicked';

Comment: change path in  form action like that http://localhost:1337/PhpProject1/index.php/search_profile_controller/profile_clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your action

```
action="http://localhost:1337/PhpProject1/search_profile_controller/profile_clicked"
```

to

```
action="<?php echo base_url() ?>search_profile_controller/profile_clicked"
```

Comment: when i use base_url() my css and jquery doen't load Its just show header and rest of the page is blank

Comment: @user2848909 happy to help